# update the page data using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, page-refresh

If i clicked on books link he will sort the book in ascending and if i clicked again he sort them in descending , but he didn't do this action unless i clicked on next or prev submit, why he didn't update the page with out clicked on next or prev ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sorter").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var order_by_value = $('input[name="order_by"]').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
       url: "" + 'http://test.local/UUser.php?action=getBooks',
      data:{
     'order_by_value': order_by_value,

     // button: 'button',
      },
      success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        if(order_by_value == "ASC"){
       $('input[name="order_by"]').val("DESC");
      }
      else {
       $('input[name="order_by"]').val("ASC");
       }
     // $('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');
    }
   });
});
});
```

and this is my function

```
public function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2, $order = "ASC")
 {
   $sql_start = $start * $limit;
   $sql_limit = $limit;
   $sql_order_by = $order;

   $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook, userBook.book_id, userBook.user_id FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username ORDER BY Library.nameOfBook $sql_order_by LIMIT $sql_start, $sql_limit";
   $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
   $statment->execute([
       ':username' => $this->username
   ]);
   $result = $statment->fetchAll();

  echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'>

  <tr>
   <th><a id='sorter' href='#'>Books</a></th>
   <th>Action</th>
   </tr>";
   foreach($result as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' id='delete".$row['book_id']."-".$row['user_id']."' onclick='deleteBook(this)' name='delete' value='Delete'>" . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
   echo "";
   return count($result);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this event is listening on an element with Id sorter, so it's working properly, you just need to display the answer from the server to the client

```
success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        if(order_by_value == "ASC"){
       $('input[name="order_by"]').val("DESC");
      }
      else {
       $('input[name="order_by"]').val("ASC");
       }
     // $('input[name="current"]').trigger('click');
     //here you display the result from the server
    $("#myTable").html(res);
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer and show be placed as a comment.

Comment: now I added the answer, I can't add comments because of my reputation, now I can

Comment: he give this error Notice: Undefined property: User::$username 
in this part of function getbooks ':username' => $this->username

Comment: that seems to be a problem with your class, isn't finding the username, maybe you have to fetch it from session?

Comment: seems like your class, doesn't find username, is the method getBooks inside the class? I can't know where's the problem, but the problem now is in the code not on ajax side

Comment: this is my code  can you check it please ? @joaquinjsb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171675/discussion-between-joaquinjsb-and-husam-almasri).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from just the AJAX function itself. The logic seems fine. Perhaps you're not targeting the specific element, or the structure of the HTML code has some logical flaw as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This does not provide an answer and show be placed as a comment.

Comment: I'm not allowed to add comments :s

Says I need 50 rep